# How to add regions in drupal 7 theme

Tags: theming

I wanna know how to add regions on a zen drupal 7 theme. I'm using the neptune sub-theme. I have altered the .info file. But i cant find the layout.css to adjust the region sizes.

Comment: How to alter the width of the regions. I'm trying to have three column header

Comment: If this is a purely CSS question, it is off topic here. Also, there is no universal answer for that, it depends too much on what CSS you use (both in base theme and your alterations so far).

Comment: Detail blog: http://goo.gl/kD3TZu